Error in Ollama Functions js (Error(Failed to parse a function call from ${this.llm.model} output: ${chatGenerationContent}))
Can you help me please with this , i try to use ollama to make a chat that can call tools in order to answer to the the user question, I use the same documentation in langachain langchain openai call tools, so i just changed openai with ollama.The error that i get is this :  ollama_langchain/node_modules/@langchain/community/dist/experimental/chat_models/ollama_functions.js:97
throw new Error(Failed to parse a function call from ${this.llm.model} output: ${chatGenerationContent});
^
Error: Failed to parse a function call from llama2 output: {
"tool": "getAge",
"tool_input": {
"person": "Alice L."
},
"output": 27
}
at OllamaFunctions._generate (file:///C:/Users/YassineES-SADANY/Downloads/ollama_langchain/node_modules/@langchain/community/dist/experimental/chat_models/ollama_functions.js:97:19)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
at async OllamaFunctions._generateUncached (file:///C:/Users/YassineES-SADANY/Downloads/ollama_langchain/node_modules/@langchain/core/dist/language_models/chat_models.js:169:29)
at async OllamaFunctions.invoke (file:///C:/Users/YassineES-SADANY/Downloads/ollama_langchain/node_modules/@langchain/core/dist/language_models/chat_models.js:53:24)
at async RunnableSequence.invoke (file:///C:/Users/YassineES-SADANY/Downloads/ollama_langchain/node_modules/@langchain/core/dist/runnables/base.js:1120:33)
at async file:///C:/Users/YassineES-SADANY/Downloads/ollama_langchain/zod_ollama.js:123:5
Node.js v20.12.2.  Here is my code  :
import { z } from "zod";
import { DynamicStructuredTool } from "@langchain/core/tools";
import { OllamaFunctions } from "@langchain/community/experimental/chat_models/ollama_functions";
import { JsonOutputToolsParser } from "langchain/output_parsers";
import {
  RunnableLambda,
  RunnablePassthrough,
  RunnableSequence,
} from "@langchain/core/runnables";
import { convertToOpenAITool } from "@langchain/core/utils/function_calling";

const toolSystemPromptTemplate = `You are an assistant that has access to the following set of tools. Here are the names and descriptions for each tool:
{tools}
To use a tool, respond with a JSON object with the following structure:
{{
  "tool": <name of the called tool>,
  "tool_input": <parameters for the tool matching the above JSON schema>
  "output": <output of the tool>
}}`;
    const addTool = new DynamicStructuredTool({
    name: "add",
    description: "Add two integers together.",
    schema: z.object({
        firstInt: z.number(),
        secondInt: z.number(),
    }),
    func: async ({ firstInt, secondInt }) => {
        return (firstInt + secondInt).toString();
    },
    });

    const multiplyTool = new DynamicStructuredTool({
        name: "multiply",
        description: "Multiply two integers together.",
        schema: z.object({
        firstInt: z.number(),
        secondInt: z.number(),
        }),
        func: async ({ firstInt, secondInt }) => {
        return (firstInt * secondInt).toString();
        },
    });
    
    const exponentiateTool = new DynamicStructuredTool({
        name: "exponentiate",
        description: "Exponentiate the base to the exponent power.",
        schema: z.object({
        base: z.number(),
        exponent: z.number(),
        }),
        func: async ({ base, exponent }) => {
        return (base ** exponent).toString();
        },
    });

    const getAgeTool = new DynamicStructuredTool({
        name: "getAge",
        description: "Get the age of a person. The tool accepts a string with the person's name and returns their age.",
        schema: z.object({
            person: z.string(),
        }),
        func: async ({person}) => {
            switch (person) {
                case "Bob K.":
                    return "Bob is 45 years old.";
                case "Alice L.":
                    return "Alice is 32 years old.";
                default:
                    return "I don't know how old that person is.";
            }

        }
    });


    const model = new OllamaFunctions({
        model: "llama2",
        toolSystemPromptTemplate,
    })

    const tools = [getAgeTool, multiplyTool, exponentiateTool, addTool];
    
    const toolMap = {
        multiply: multiplyTool,
        exponentiate: exponentiateTool,
        add: addTool,
        getAge: getAgeTool,
    } ;

    const modelWithTools = model.bind({
        functions: tools.map(convertToOpenAITool),
    });

    // Function for dynamically constructing the end of the chain based on the model-selected tool.
    const callSelectedTool = RunnableLambda.from(
    (toolInvocation) => {
        const selectedTool = toolMap[toolInvocation.type];
        if (!selectedTool) {
        throw new Error(
            `No matching tool available for requested type "${toolInvocation.type}".`
        );
        }
        const toolCallChain = RunnableSequence.from([
        (toolInvocation) => toolInvocation.args,
        selectedTool,
        ]);
        // We use `RunnablePassthrough.assign` here to return the intermediate `toolInvocation` params
        // as well, but you can omit if you only care about the answer.
        return toolCallChain;
    }
    );

    const chain = RunnableSequence.from([
    modelWithTools,
    new JsonOutputToolsParser(),
    // .map() allows us to apply a function for each item in a list of inputs.
    // Required because the model can call multiple tools at once.
    callSelectedTool.map(),
    ]);

    await chain.invoke("How old Alice L. is?");

